# how a macro definition is passed from Makefile to a header file?

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I am trying to compile the source code twice with a MACRO defined & undefined. So for default the macro is undefined & i want to define this macro through arguments from Makefile, like

```
$(MAKE) -c $(present_dir)/new_dir -DONE_MACRO=1
```

so i am using this `ONE_MACRO` in `file.h`.
how this definition is reflected and knows to preprocessor. Here im using `cygmake`. How to pass an `MACRO as argument to compiler` with **cygmake** tool.

file.h:-

```
#if ONE_MACRO
  #define some_targets
#else
 #define other_targets
#endif
```

So how this **ONE_MACRO** is defined from make file, im trying to pass macro as argument as below

Makefile:-

```
MY_TARGET:
    $(MAKE) -C $(present_dir)/target_dir -D ONE_MACRO=1 $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) shows how to use `#ifdef` within `file.h`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.  The compiler treats the `-D MACRO_DEFINE=1` argument (conventionally written without the space between the option letter `D` and the value `MACRO_DEFINE=1`) as if there was a line of code that read `#define MACRO_DEFINE 1`.  This is set before any of the actual code is processed.  That's straight-forward, so it probably isn't what you're asking — but it isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to pass a **macro to compiler from Makefile as an argument**, this Macro is using in `file.h`.so while compiling i'll compile the `file.h` **twice based on the macro as defined & undefined**. I think its clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every compiler there is an environmental variable, which passes the areguments to compiler/linker. while dealing with other than GCC we need to find that environmental variables before usage.

like wise in my case **RVCT31_CCOPT** is the variable which passes the arguments to compiler while building.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to do what I think you want:

define_test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef X
#define X 1
#endif

int
main()
{
    printf("X = %d\n", X);
}
```

Makefile:

```
X = 1
CPPFLAGS += -DX=$(X)

define_test: FORCE
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) define_test.c -o $@

FORCE:
```

Then to pass a different value for macro X:

```
make X=2
```

(This assumes you want the value of the macro to be an integer; if you want the value to be a string, you have to get a bit more tricky with quoting properly.)

You can also add the definition directly to the CPPFLAGS, e.g.:

`make CPPFLAGS+=-DX=2`

Comment: i tried this concept, but the cygmake is giving me invalid option 
`cygmake: invalid option -- D`.

Comment: Of course `-D` is invalid option to make; it's an option to the precompiler.  You say you "tried the concept", but what **exactly** did you type?  Did you type e.g., `make CPPFLAGS+=-DONE_MACRO=1` ?

Comment: yes, i have appended the macro with -D to CPPFLAGS.
here the compiler and its arguments are given through codeblocks configuration file .cbp. Main Makefile will call sub folder makefiles there this cbp file gets executed and compiles the code.

Comment: I am seeing difference when the Macro is defined in header file & Macro is Passing an argument to compiler. The disassembly gives me difference.